# Can I Paste on Multiple Lines?

Tags: java

I need to assign 275 variables with the Double type. Is there a way I can paste word Double on all 275 lines at once? I have been pasting Double on each line and its tiring.(I also have to add the underscores to replace spaces in the variable identifiers. If anyone knows a shortcut for that let me know.)

```
//Multicolor cards.
   Double Aether_Helix
   Double Beledros_Witherbloom
   Double Biomathematician
   165 Blade Historian
   166 Blood Researcher
   167 Blot Out the Sky
   168 Body of Research
   169 Closing Statement
   170 Cram Session
   171 Creative Outburst
   172 Culling Ritual
   173 Culmination of Studies
   174 Daemogoth_Titan
   175 Daemogoth_Woe-Eater
   176 Deadly_Brew
   177 Decisive_Denial
   178 Dina,_Soul_Steeper
   179 Double_Major
   180 Dramatic_Finale
   181 Elemental_Expressionist
   182 Elemental_Masterpiece
   183 Elemental_Summoning
   184 Eureka_Moment
   185 Exhilarating_Elocution
   186 Expressive_Iteration
   187 Fractal_Summoning
   188 Fracture
   189 Galazeth_Prismari
   190 Golden_Ratio
```

Comment: Before you do that, really make sure you actually want that. You would then have a class with 275 variable, does that sound maintainable?

Comment: **1.** Sometimes an editor has column selection per mouse (Alt+mouse drag or such). Select a zero width colum befor the "1" and then type "Double " there. With a bit of luck the editor will fill every line with "Double ". **2.** Or use regex replace. Select the lines, and do a replace in selection: `^  (\d+) (.*)$` with `  array[$1] = "$2";`.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this question seems to me to possibly be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. For example, I wonder if rather than editing this to create a bunch of doubles, you use this as a data-entry text file, and read it into , perhaps, a `Map<String, Double>`, or something similar.

Comment: .... @user15793316: Yours is even better than my suggestion: Cleaner and more extendable

Comment: The main issue in my mind is that you (the OP) appear to be confounding data with code. That list of text and numbers looks to be data, something that you might not want to hard-code into your program, but rather leave as data, allowing for changes to it at a later date, if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a tool like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) to make the changes you need.

I was able to convert the list you supplied by using "CTRL+H" to open the replace dialog, using regular expression mode, and replacing "\d+" with "Double":

```
Double Blade Historian
Double Blood Researcher
Double Blot Out the Sky
Double Body of Research
Double Closing Statement
Double Cram Session
Double Creative Outburst
Double Culling Ritual
Double Culmination of Studies
Double Daemogoth_Titan
Double Daemogoth_Woe-Eater
Double Deadly_Brew
Double Decisive_Denial
Double Dina,_Soul_Steeper
Double Double_Major
Double Dramatic_Finale
Double Elemental_Expressionist
Double Elemental_Masterpiece
Double Elemental_Summoning
Double Eureka_Moment
Double Exhilarating_Elocution
Double Expressive_Iteration
Double Fractal_Summoning
Double Fracture
Double Galazeth_Prismari
Double Golden_Ratio
```

Comment: I should also add that I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020-09